# Is it possible to 'become' a role or only to 'undertake' one?

Tags: grammar

> To become to the role of operations manager

Is this sentence correct in its structure? Or is it not possible to 'become' a role, only to 'undertake' one?

Comment: Well, “to become **to** the role” is certainly not grammatical. Apart from that, you’re talking _semantics_, not grammar. _Become_ can grammatically take a noun phrase as its object, and _the role of operations manager_ is a noun phrase. So is _Aristotelian philosophy_, so grammatically speaking, “to become Aristotelian philosophy” is fine. But how would you like to be transformed from a human being into an abstract entity like philosophy or a role? Personally, I’d prefer to remain physical.

Comment: @Janus: I wouldn't be too sure about that. There's certainly nothing wrong with, for example, [*The new law states that “it shall be unlawful for any person in any public place or in view of the public to be found in a state of nudity, or partial nudity, or in dress **not becoming to** his or her sex.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22not+becoming+to+his+or%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), and I don't see anything "ungrammatical" about *Your conduct does not **become** the role [or better, **office**] of a senior manager* (i.e. - reflects badly on the position).

Comment: @Fumble That’s the adjective _becoming_, though, which is slightly different. You can have attire that is becoming to you, or you can have attire that becomes you; but you wouldn’t have attire that becomes to you. And I did say specifically that there’s nothing ungrammatical about “to become the role of operations manager”—it’s just semantically off (especially if we’re talking about _become_ in the sense of _turn into_, rather than _suit_).

Comment: @Janus: My first example is indeed "verb participle used adjectivally", but the second one is a straightforward verb ***used as a verb***. If OP actually doesn't understand such usages in the first place, the question should be on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). I do not think ELU is here to ***teach*** normal English.

Comment: @Fumble But your verbal example _does not have an extra **to** in it_, which is the only thing that made the sentence in the question ungrammatical as such.

Comment: @Janus: Mark Twain, *On the Decay of the Art of Lying* (1880) - [*It would not **become to** me to criticise you, gentlemen*.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22would+not+become+to+me+to+criticise+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) Dated phrasing, maybe, but hardly "ungrammatical" in my book.

Comment: @Fumble Well, we’ll have to disagree there. Definitely as ungrammatical in my modern-day book as “the rest of the ground is become into small tenements” (from Howell’s _Londinopolis_).

Answer (score 1):

'To become the role of operations manager' is correct grammar - [to become][the][ role of operations manager] is [infinitive verb][definite article][noun phrase], which is correct.

On the other hand, it doesn't make any sense - what you mean is 'come to the role of operations manager', 'become operations manager', or '[behaviour] becoming to the role of operations manager'

Answer (score -1):

Become the role, even without the "to", doesn't quite work. One could "become the Operations Manager" or one could "take on the role of Operations Manager".